# Webpack bundling mechanism

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, webpack-4

I'm reaching out to you in order to request for support to optimize our frontend application's loading time on the client side. Please find below more details about the situation.

**Context**

Our frontend application is hosted with Heroku (We use 2 standard 1x dynos). The web dynos are responsible of 2 things:

Serving the static assets of our single page application (SPA) built with Vue.js
Acting as a proxy to communicate with the backend.

Here is the list of technologies that we use in frontend application:

- We use Vue.js with Vue CLI 3.
- We use Webpack for bundling.
- We use Node-Express.js for hosting the static assets.
- We use Raygun as real user monitoring.
- We use Fastly as a CDN for serving the static assets (js, css and images).
- We use Service Worker for serving assets from the browser cache.

Problem
Our main problem is the loading time on the client side: Raygun, our real user monitoring tool, reports an average loading time of ~10.4 secs.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFhhO.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5i73.png)

**Problem**

- Our main problem is the loading time on the client side: Raygun, our real user monitoring tool, reports an average loading time of ~10.4 secs.
- We would like to improve the loading time of the pages that get loaded from the entry point main.js (we have 2 entry point main.js & signup.js)
- We believe that the problem is related to the optimization of our webpack chunking strategy. The Webpack chunking is setup in the vue.config.js file.

**Constraints**

- We use the Service Worker in order to load the frontend assets from the browser cache. We noticed that the Service Worker registration takes more that 2-3 secs if the number of chunks is above 100 chunks.

**Questions**

- What would be the optimization that we could do in order to improve the loading time? (Please find below the vue.config.js file)

**Reference**

- Please find below our source code of vue.config.js file:

```js
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          prependData: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/generics/variables.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/generics/spacing.scss";
          @import "@/assets/scss/generics/sizing.scss";
          `
        },
      },
    },
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '^/auth': {
            target: process.env.JB_BACKEND_URL,
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {'^/auth' : '/api/v1.0/get-token/'}
        },
        '^/api': {
            target: process.env.JB_BACKEND_URL,
            changeOrigin: true
        },
      }
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
      // delete default entry point 'app'
      config.entryPoints.delete("app").end();
      //delete default 'html' plugin - in case you don't want default index.html file
      //delete 'prefetch' and 'preload' plugins which are dependent on 'html' plugin
      config.plugins
        .delete("html")
        .delete("prefetch")
        .delete("preload");

      config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

      config.plugin('CompressionPlugin').use(CompressionPlugin);
    },
    pluginOptions: {
      webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
        openAnalyzer: false
      }
    },
    configureWebpack:{
      entry: {
        index: "./src/main.js",
        signup: "./src/signup.js"
      },
      output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.[hash].js"
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: "public/index.html",
          inject: true,
          filename: "index.html",
          chunks: ["index"]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: "public/signup.html",
          inject: true,
          filename: "signup.html",
          chunks: ["signup"]
        }),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
          // these options encourage the ServiceWorkers to get in there fast
          // and not allow any straggling "old" SWs to hang around
          clientsClaim: true,
          skipWaiting: false, // Since we load chunks with hash in it.
          // Do not cache images on service worker registration
          exclude: [/\.(?:png|gif|ttf|jpg|jpeg|svg|gz)$/],
          runtimeCaching: [
              // Some code goes here (Hidden)
          ]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
          maxChunks: 30,
        }),
        // Ignore all locale files of moment.js
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        // Import 3rd party environment variables
        new Dotenv({
          path: './.env', // load '.env'
          safe: false, // load '.env.example' to verify the '.env' variables are all set. Can also be a string to a different file.
          allowEmptyValues: true, // allow empty variables (e.g. `FOO=`) (treat it as empty string, rather than missing)
          systemvars: true, // load all the predefined 'process.env' variables which will trump anything local per dotenv specs.
          silent: true // hide any errors
        }),
      ],
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all'
        },
      },
    },
    publicPath: process.env.STATIC_PATH || "/"
  }
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like that:

```js
module.exports =
{
  configureWebpack: (config) =>
  {
    config.optimization = {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      moduleIds: 'hashed',
      splitChunks:
      {
        automaticNameDelimiter: '_',
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: 5,
        minSize: 5000,
        //maxSize: 250000,
        cacheGroups:
        {
          default:
          {
                minChunks: 2,
                priority: -20,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
          vendor:
          {
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name(module)
            {
              // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
              // or node_modules/packageName
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/]([^\\/]+)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `vendor_${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```